# How to share broadband Internet connection of one computer with another computer?

Tags: networking, laptop, internet, broadband

I want to share my Internet connection (broadband) in my desktop PC to my laptop. I don't know how to achieve this. My desktop doesn't have Bluetooth. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ICS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126) to connect them via Ethernet (you would need a 2nd NIC in the desktop) or you could use ICS if you had a wireless card in your desktop and set up an Ad-Hoc wifi network to your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to achieve this is by using a router.  Your internet connection will be connected to the router.  Your desktop and laptop will also be connected to the router.  This could either be with a network cable or a wireless network connection (802.11 b/g/n).  The router will handle distributing the internet connection to the two computers.