# Run an ADSL connection (Internet+local net) on two computers (PC and laptop) at the same time

Tags: network-shares, internet-connection, adsl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use broadband internet connection of one computer with another computer](https://superuser.com/questions/146710/how-to-use-broadband-internet-connection-of-one-computer-with-another-computer)

I'm using a hub to connect them. I get online only on one comp, while the second PC can't connect (it says `...invalid in this domain`). However local sites are running in both PCs at the same time.

Please help me surf the Internet at the same time on both machines, independently. My ADSL modem is a TP-Link TD-8817. Some said it has no function such as 'dual access mode, etc...'. I'm running Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two IPs on your adsl circuit? Hooking up two computers to a switch or hub that is connected to an ADSL modem will only work if each computer is configured with its own IP and setup to pull that IP off the adsl connection, which of course means you need two static IPs on that connection. This is called a Parallel connection to an ISP, and some ISPs won't offer very good support for this. Most will recommend you don't use a hub at all.